# Vite doesnt bundle everything in the correct folder

Tags: javascript, directory, vite, directory-structure

Lets first introduce my file system:
[image]

I'm trying to make the bundled files inside the `client` folder (main.js, style.css ...) to go inside the `public` folder as listed above,

Instead a dist folder appears in the `Client/` folder.

This is my vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'src',
  build: {
    outDir: '../../public',
  },

  entry: 'main.js',
});
```

My `package.json` for the npm run build script (the build script before was "build" : vite build src --emptyOutDir   but i had to drag out index.html outside of src because that was what vite recognized as root)

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build  --emptyOutDir",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

And lastly the index.html ( idk if you need it)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I had a lot of other problems read some of the docs, resolved but it just kept creating more.
As you can infer this is the first project i used vite in and i dont really know its inner workings.
I have been debugging for hours and need someone else with a clear mind to solve this stupid problem of mine, because my mind is burned.

-Thanks for taking the time to read this

I tried lots of things because the `npm run dev` wasnt working correctly and while it fixed that now `npm run build` is broken...

Comment: Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, **data/folder structures**, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: there is no error.. if that was the case i wwould try to solve it myself, take a look $ npm run build

> client@0.0.0 build       
> vite build  --emptyOutDir

vite v4.4.9 building for production...

styles/style.css doesn't exist at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
✓ 4 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                 0.45 kB │ gzip: 0.28 kB
dist/assets/index-cb5a6f38.css  0.02 kB │ gzip: 0.04 kB
dist/assets/index-a80a1ace.js   0.79 kB │ gzip: 0.45 kB
✓ built in 198ms

Comment: Please see the boldfaced bit of the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I can't replicate the problem locally. I created a new project (via `npm create vite@latest`) in a `client` directory next to an empty `public` directory, moved the source files into a `src` subdirectory, and added your `vite.config.js`. When I do a build, the files get built and put in the correct `public` directory (the peer of `client`) as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it on my own. The problem is in my `root` directory, I had seperated my vite config file from my index.html and the src folder...

Anyway big mess. I just moved my index.html into the `client/src` folder

Reconfigured the `package.json` like this:

```js
 "dev": "vite src",
 "build": "vite build src --emptyOutDir",
```

and the `vite.config.js` like this:

```js
// client/src/vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'src',
  build: {
    outDir: '../../public',
  },

  entry: 'main.js',
});
```